definition of regular estimators
In the book "Semiparametric Theory and Missing Data" by Tsiatis, superefficient estimators are defined as "they are unnatural and have undesirable local properties associated with them". The example given is Hodges' estimator, which has arbitrarily high mean squared error in a neighborhood of the point of superefficiency for finite sample sizes.
Therefore the notion of a regular estimator is introduced (given here), which is an estimator that has a limiting distribution in shrinking neighborhoods that does not depend on the local data-generating process.
However, there are estimators in higher dimensions than 1, such as the James-Stein estimator, that are not regular (same link) but do not have the finite sample issues that the Hodges' estimator does. This estimator has uniformly smaller MSE than the maximum likelihood estimator at all sample sizes (Example 3 here).
Therefore the definiton of a regular estimator rules out some estimators for reasons other than poor MSE in a neighborhood of the point of superefficiency. Is there some other reason that non-regular estimators should be "unnatural"? Does not being regular end leaving this estimators not robust to model misspecification or something?

Superefficiency is a property of an unbiased estimator claiming to beat the Cramer Rao bound. Hodge's example leads to the understanding that this bound is well defined, and a violation of this implies the estimator is irregular. Once you allow for biased estimators you can easily beat the MSE of many "optimal unbiased" estimators. James-Stein is just one such example. I don't know if that answers your question though.

@AdamO You mean unbiased in finite samples? I didn't know that was part of the definition. See here for example the definition on p.398 here . Actually the entire narrative, that superefficient estimators are a problem for Fisher's program of showing MLE's are efficient, doesn't make sense if we're only talking about unbiased estimators, because neither do MLE's have to be unbiased.

MLE is all asymptotic theory. It is asymptotically unbiased, and it asymptotically achieves the CR bound under some conditions. In finite samples, that MLE might be garbage. But for this case, we are talking about UMVUE estimators which are regular, unbiased, and achieve the CR bound full stop. I guess the MSE of an MLE is always worse than that of an UMVUE when an UMVUE exists - that is that the variance of the MLE is still higher than the CR bound. Maybe you know that to be wrong, or have a counterexample?

Regularity doesn't rule out superefficiency completely, but it does tame it a lot. The relative efficiency of the James-Stein estimator converges to 1 as the sample size increases.  (Since regularity is an asymptotic property, it makes sense to consider asymptotic efficiency when discussing it)
More generally, the Convolution Theorem says that any regular estimator is asymptotically equivalent to the efficient estimator plus random noise, so that regular estimators cannot be asymptotically superefficient.  Non-regular estimators can be asymptotically superefficient (though only on a set of parameter values of Lebesgue measure zero.)
Non-regular estimators aren't necessarily 'unnatural' -- the lasso regression estimator is non-regular at coefficient values containing any zeros -- but regularity is still an important property, in particular for its relationship to validity of the bootstrap.
